# How to use seperate js files in Laravel Blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to have different JS files for each Blade View in Laravel to help keep the project structure clean.

My problem is, when I try to access a function from that JS file in a Blade view, the console returns an error of:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick*

But the file is there and it logs the console message from that js file.

Here are my files and structure:

**resources/js/index.js**

```
console.log("Hello from index js");

function myFunc() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

**resources/views/layout/master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       @yield('content')
       {{-- @yield('js') --}}
       @stack('js')
    </body>
</html>
```

**resources/views/index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
    <h1>Works</h1>
    <button onclick="myFunc()">Click</button>
@endsection
@push('js')
<script src="{{ asset('js/index.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

**webpackmix.mix.js**

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").postCss(
    "resources/css/app.css",
    "public/css",
    [
        //
    ]
);

mix.js("resources/js/index.js", "public/js");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function defined in script that loaded after main body content, but you trying to access this function in main body content.

- Try to switch to selector for the button in JS file
- Or load script sync before body (BAD: defers content render)

Comment: Okay I see, thanks Victor, but why is it that if I place my JS code between two script tags in the index.blade.php instead of providing the src to the JS file, it works?

Comment: @MurrayOB, seems like there is working variable hoisting

Comment: Using document.querySelector and adding an eventListener worked.

Answer (score 0):

@murrayOB you can just create your separate js file in public and then js folder and just include it in your default.blade.php file like that `<script src="{{asset('js/common-flow.js')}}"></script>`
and after that just call any function from blade file written in that specific common-flow file